# Extract data from a cell depending on the value of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet in **Google Sheet** that changes the values of certain cells depending on the value of a dropdown cell.

From **Google App Scripts** how could I access those values without changing the dropdown value (since using `setValue("xxx")`, on the dropdown cell, would change all the values in the sheet)

For example :

In this Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v1cR9CpxtU1QSp4nLeT7GMCrA3Uxyd0HdqdBERv4qgg/edit?usp=sharing The idea is get the age of C without changing the value in the dropdown, and don't going to look at the direct value in the table (because the real example pass throught many formulas).

Answer (score 0):

```
// example pulling range B2:C6
let vals = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B2:C6").getValues();
// vals will be a 2D array containing the values in those cells.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this doesn't work for me.

I'm getting a [[Y]] (with only one value, not the list of possible values)

More specifically: I'm trying to get the value that a cell should have if a dropdown has an **X** value. The cell value is gived by the formula ```=INDEX('Sheet 1'!A1:A;EQUIV(A2;'Sheet 1'!AK1:AK;0);1)```

Comment: You want a list of the candidate values of the drop down?

Comment: No. Only the value of the cell if the dropdown has an X value.

For example:

The cell "B1" is the dropdown that contains 3 posibles values (A, B, C)
The cell "B2" is a cell that has the age that change depending the choice in "B1".

How I can get given the age of person C without doing ```sheet.getRange("B1").setValue("C")``` because that will modify the sheet.

Comment: Please lay out a concrete example and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: I created this example Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v1cR9CpxtU1QSp4nLeT7GMCrA3Uxyd0HdqdBERv4qgg/edit?usp=sharing

The idea is get the age of C without changing the value in the dropdown, and don't going to look at the direct value in the table (because the real example pass throught many formulas). I supposed that this can be achieved using DataValidators but I'm not sure

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay.  Here's a function that works on the example you provided.  It builds up an object/dict/hash table (whatever you want to call it) based on columns A and B, and then you can easily select the value you want.

```
function myFunction(person) {
  let vals = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:B").getValues();
  
  vals = vals.filter(val => val[0] !== "");   // get rid of empty rows
  console.log(vals);
  let dict = vals.reduce((acc, val)=> {acc[val[0]] = val[1]; return acc}, {})
  console.log(dict);
  return dict[person]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think that is a good solution because you are indexing directly from the table, in the real case I'm using there are like tons of formulas, including charts depending on the user. For the moment I'm using (in the example): 


`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

sheet.getRange("E3").setValue("C");
return sheet.getRange("F3").getValue();`

Comment: you didn't state that as part of your prompt or in the example data you gave.  I'm not sure what else you want.